# How to use Apache Tika Server 2.5 as API and call this in .net6?

Tags: api, .net-6.0, apache-tika, tika-server

planning to use Apache Tika Server 2.5 in .net6. how can we use that and call from .net component.

Comment: Install java, start the server, make REST calls to it?

Comment: Have downloaded Apache tika standard 2.5 and started server using below command
> Java -jar tika-server-standard-2.5.0.jar and started browsing endpoints but few are not accessible i.e. tika/form and rmeta/form

Comment: @Gagravarr want to send multiple file formats and parse at once in API call but unable to do it.

Comment: See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaServer#TikaServer-TikaServerServices for the list of supported endpoints, and if they are GET / POST / PUT

Comment: @Gagravarr  Thanks for reply..yes we have endpoints Tika/form and rmeta/form listed on confluence but when we start the server and browse url http://localhost:9998/ and then select these endpoints by clicking on them then it shows this page isn't working right now and exception we get is HTTP 405 method not allowed.

Comment: As documented on the Wiki and in the App, those methods require a POST, so a GET won't work

Comment: @Gagravarr making post call but getting error - Problem with writing the data, class org.Apache.tika.server.core. resource, contenttype: text/xml

Comment: @Gagravarr in case you have reference document or snippet to call tika server from .net using multipart.that helps.

Comment: I don't code in .net, but you can find a bunch of Java ones which should be pretty similar in the Apache Tika test suite, eg https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-server/tika-server-standard/src/test/java/org/apache/tika/server/standard/TikaResourceTest.java#L533

Comment: @Gagravarr Does tika keeps parent child relationship in document and attachments

Comment: Depends on what API you call - some will skip attachments, some will inline, some will return you a bundle with references. Up to you what one works best in your situation

Comment: @Gagravarr for multipart support when I was trying to call post Api endpoint tika/form or rmeta/form by attaching 2 documents it's only accept 1St document and parse.

Comment: @Gagravarr i think we cannot pass multiple files in single request to tika/form or rmeta/form endpoints

Comment: You'd be better off asking Tika usage questions on the user mailing list, lots more people monitor that - https://tika.apache.org/mail-lists.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's worked for me

```
Var Client=new Httpclient();     
string uriString="Your API endpoint Address here";
Using var stream=File.OpenRead(filename); Using var content= new MultiFormDataContent{{ new StreamContent (stream)}};  
HttpResponseMesage response=client.PostAsync(uriString,content).Result;
```